# Can you use logic in views? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, dry

I am a beginner developer and I have been reading a lot about the subject but no one is very clear whether you can or can't use logic in your views.

I understand that complex logic should not be used but I am wondering if things that can be seen as view related logic can be used. I am talking about something along the lines of this:

`<%=image_tag(group.icon.url, alt: 'Image', class: 'profile-image', id: 'target') if group.icon?%`

or maybe something like this can be used.

```
 <% if logged_in? %>
    <div class="user-avatar d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
        <%=image_tag(current_user.avatar.url, alt: 'Image', class: "avatar-icon") if current_user.avatar?%>
        <h3><%=current_user.name%></h3>
    </div>

    <li class="d-flex menu">
        <div class="icons"><%= image_tag "icons/log_in.svg", alt: "Groups", class: "icons"%></div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center pl-2">
            <%=link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user), class: "link" %></div>
    </li>
    <li class="d-flex menu">
        <div class="icons"><%= image_tag "icons/time.svg", alt: "Groups", class: "icons"%></div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center pl-2">
            <%=link_to "My Group Transactions", user_times_path(current_user), class: "link" %></div>
    </li>
<%end%>
```

This could be solved using a partial and a helper method that renders the partial but that, in my opinion, would make the view more obscure to anyone trying to understand the code. It also creates a new partial that will be used just one time. Also, in case you have more cases like this in your app then you would have to create more helper methods and partials.

If you paid close attention,

```
<%=image_tag(current_user.avatar.url, alt: 'Image', class: "avatar-icon") if current_user.avatar?%>
<%=image_tag(group.icon.url, alt: 'Image', class: 'profile-image', id: 'target') if group.icon?%
```

You realized, that these are similar methods but they are not the same. So, in this case, it is easy to create 2 helper methods or maybe create a method that allows for the developer to build the desired `img_tag` through parameters but both solutions seem more troublesome than just using an inline `if` statement.

I would like to know precisely if it is considered a good practice to have view related logic on the view and, if it is, of what kind and to what extent. Any resources on the subject would be very appreciated.

Comment: Read the comment thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528396/where-should-simple-methods-used-in-the-view-be-defined#comment112338322_63528396

Comment: Although not ruby, the answers here are actually correctly formulated as in… The way MVC should be is language agnostic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284641/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-logic-in-view

Answer (score 2):

> Can you use logic in views? Rails

Yes, you can. **But you should avoid complex logic and ActiveRecord stuff.**
Simple if-else is fine.

Talking about DRYing image tags using helpers:

```
<%=image_tag(current_user.avatar.url, alt: 'Image', class: "avatar-icon") if current_user.avatar?%>
<%=image_tag(group.icon.url, alt: 'Image', class: 'profile-image', id: 'target') if group.icon?%
```

If you check there actually only one similarity `alt: 'Image'` and even you might want to change it to some other meaningful alt value like 'avatar' or 'group icon'.
So in this particular scenario writing helper method does not add much value.