# Where should simple methods used in the view be defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I so far know how to define and use methods in each of the model, controller and view.

The view tends to be a mess when I enter complex logic (compared to `.rb` files like the model or controller), mostly due to the extra tags required when using ruby code in the view.

Where is the most appropriate place to define a method such that it can be accessed by the view?

Note: as it stands, complex logic in the view is not even a method, so any suggestions / best practices will provide significant improvement.

#### Example

Here's an example of a simple method I use in the view (it changes a true/false to a word for a human to read

```rb
def available_in_words(time_slot_available)
  if time_slot_available == true 
    "Available"
  else
    "Unavailable"
  end
end
```

Comment: Some people will say `helpers`. Some people will say `presenters`. Some people will say something else. Opinions will vary depending on use case or other context, experiences with different approaches, and more. So, it's pretty hard to say what is "most appropriate". It is, IMO, appropriate to get *all* ruby out of your views.

Comment: @jvillian all of those answers help me a lot. I only have one to start with. I guess helpers is a good place? Are there reasons for choosing one place over another? Are the various options (and rationale for each) summarised somewhere - I googled but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: @jvillian also, if I define a method in helpers, will it automatically be available in the view (without anything else needing to be done)?

Comment: @stevec Can you edit the question to include the code you are asking about? Or an example of it?

Comment: @RockwellRice sure, will update now

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+helpers) will get you started on helpers. In terms of a summarisation, I don't know. I haven't used helpers in years: I use an exclusive combination of presenters and decorators. I recall that there is a lot written on presenters and decorators and such but you would have to scrounge around the bottom drawers of the Interwhozits and see what's crawling around.

Comment: @RockwellRice updated

Comment: @jvillian thanks, all good to know. Right now I don't know the differences, but I'll read up on them.

Comment: Ya, something like that I would put in a helper but It also depends on if you are using across multiple views.  If this is in an `appointments_helper.rb` because it is only used in appointments that would work, if you need it in multiple views across the app you may need to put it in the application helper or something.  It really depends on some different factors.

Comment: I found the comment here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19949554 by burlesona to be enlightening. I personally, do not use helpers at all ever. Logic in views should be kept to an absolute minimum. The maximum amount of logic I put into view is a check to see if a variable is nil when determining whether or not to display something.

Comment: @KaomTe fascinating. Just so I'm sure, when we talk about 'helper methods' are we talking about any method defined in `helpers/resource_helpers.rb`? Also, "Don't use Rails Helper Methods. Just don't." is very strong! (I wouldn't have guessed not to use them, so am very glad I asked). burlesona lists 3 reasons to do it their way (not using helpers): i) "These patterns make it really easy to follow what's going on in your app ", ii) "it becomes trivial to replicate any of the behavior in your app from the Rails console", iii) "easy to test". I don't understand *why* just yet, but will read up!

Comment: @stevec A few comments down in the same thread burlesona extrapolates more on why helpers are a bad idea.

Comment: @KaomTe that's brilliant. I wonder if the answer to my question above is answered there with "For all of these reasons you’re better off defining modules and using ‘module_function’ to make the methods directly accessible. Then you can just call the methods like ‘Utils.foo_bar()’ wherever you need them." (I don't know how to do that yet, but will look into it!)

Comment: Instead of modules, consider using proper classes - then you're on your way to the world of managers, presenters, decorators, mutators, interactors, and so much more!